# onboard flash and external flash, flashing at the same time

Tags: flash, nikon-d5100, hotshoe-flash

Any thoughts as to why my on board and my new speedlight would be flashing at the same time? I have gone through the manuals and nothing seems to suggest a fix.

Comment: What brand speedlight?  Is the onboard flash popped up?

Comment: Is the external flash in the hotshoe or are you triggering it in some other way?

Comment: How is the external flash attached to the D5100? Hot shoe, wired off shoe cord, PC terminal,or wireless trigger attached to the hot shoe? What flash mode is being used?

Comment: I am using a pro master fl160 bounce flash attached to the hotshoe. The on board starts in the closed position, but then pops up, and the camera is set to full auto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To quote from the comments:

> ...and the camera is set to full auto.

There's your problem.  Right there.

When you set your camera to full auto then it takes control of all the functions.  IT decides when to pop up the internal flash and fire it, not you.  It is not aware of a 'dumb' flash on the hotshoe - one of the Nikon flashes like the SB-600 might behave a little differently but not much.

Read [your manual](http://www.nikonusa.com/pdf/manuals/dslr/D5100_EN.pdf) and look at the sections for the P,S,A,M modes which give you control of settings like when the flash should pop up and what it should do when it does.  Once you do it will be the gateway to a world of discovery as to what your camera is capable of.

Comment: Thanks,I figured that even when set to auto that the on board flash would be disabled and know that there is a different flash attached.

Comment: Setting the camera to P seemed to be the best solution for this for my use so far.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the flash probably doesn't communicate with the camera body other than to get the shutter press, so the camera body may not notice that an external flash is in use.  I would try disabling the on-board flash according to the instructions in the manual.